# Python suddenly not reading json files on MAC OS X

Tags: python, json, macos

So I have a problem with reading json files in python on my macbook. This problem is very strange since I was able to read json files until literally just a couple of minutes ago. This occurred when I changed my old json file in xcode to the new json file, see below, can somebody please help me out?

Old JSON file:

```
{
    "service 1” : {
        {
            "name" : "service 1"
        },
    }
    "service 2" : {
        {
            "name" : "service 2"
        }
    }
}
```

New JSON file:

```
{
    "services” : [
        {
            "name" : "service 1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "service 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following python script is unable to read both of the above json files:

```
import json

print "Running services: "

with open('service_list.json') as service_file:
    service_list = json.load(service_file)
    print(service_file);
```

The following errors occur when I run the script:

> Running services: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "update_checker.py", line 6, in 
>       service_list = json.load(service_file)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 290, in load
>       **kw)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>   ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 2 column 22 (char 23)

Can somebody tell me what's going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the actual JSON? It has smart-quotes mixed with regular quotes.

Comment: those are the actual json files, is there something wrong about the quote usage?

Comment: Yup it's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Without  an ASCII double quotation mark to signal the end of the key `services`, the parser keeps going, assuming that `”` is some other Unicode character that is part of the key. Eventually, it reaches the end of the line, where it encounters a newline character that isn't valid in a JSON string.

Comment: basically you have a quotation mark that's not a quotation mark... it's unicode: `u+201D: Right double quotation mark`

Comment: oh wow, thanks, I don't even know how it got there...

Comment: usually when editing with something like Word or another non-code-editor. Since you're on a Mac: Maybe TextEdit? TextEdit has smart-quote support, so...

Comment: There is an issue within those examples `”` and more over accoridng https://jsonlint.com/ validator the first example i.e. OLD json is not a json..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have smart-quotes (or as others have said, some type of unicode-based quote). You need to have regular double-quotes. Look at the end-quote for `services`:

```
{
    "services” : [
        {
            "name" : "service 1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "service 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Needs to become:

```
{
    "services" : [
        {
            "name" : "service 1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "service 2"
        }
    ]
}
```